# Render VideoJs component as HTML in React

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I created a video component in React, that creates and renders VideoJS. Some logic is added to componentDidMount logic.

In another component, I need to replace a specific HTML String code with the video component.
For example I have:

```html
<table>
  <td>
  column 1
  </td>
  <td>
  videoComesHere
  </td>
</table>
```

I want to replace videoComesHere with the video component  after being mounted and componentDidMount is called.

I tried renderToString, but this method is executed before the componentDidMount.
I need a solution that renders the component and calls the componentDidMount method before getting the component String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

- **Interoperability** between HTML and JSX isn't a desirable pattern in React.
- In such a case, Vanilla JS would be handy in manipulating DOM elements.

Here's an approach.

- Capture the substitutable values in the HTML Markup: `videoComesHere`
- Replace them into elements with identifiers/classes like `<div>`.

```html
<td>videoComesHere</td> TO <td><div id="videoWrapper">videoComesHere</div></td>
```

- Use these ids/classes as placeholders to render your **React components**.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<VideoComponent/>, document.getElementById("videoWrapper"));
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/kypt0o8w/

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Disclaimer:** This problem deals with [**dangerouslySetInnerHTML**](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
(not recommended hence the name).

Comment: I want it to call the componentDidMount after calling renderToString. So In other words, I have renderToString(Video />)

This is rendering the video but not calling the componentDidMount operation

Comment: Well I have a string, and I need to replace a specific string with the video component. then call dangerouslySetInnerHTML of the string

Comment: Got you. So this deals with text set as HTML instead of JSX and component needs to be fit in within the HTML Structure. Thats when the dangerous function plays role.